# mod_rewrite RewriteCond based on Last-modified? (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpresponse, last-modified

I know that we can easily base a RewriteCond on any http **request** header. But can we check (some of) the **response** headers that are going to be sent? In particular, the **Last-modified** one?

I want to rewrite a url only when the Last-modified date is older than 30 minutes and I'm trying to avoid the overhead of delegating that check to a php file every single time a file from that directory is requested.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outbound headers do not exist until `much` later than `mod_rewrite` is acting.  There also isn't any file-modification-time checking functionality built into `mod_rewrite`, so the closest you'd get using it is making a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap) of the External Rewriting Program variety to find out whether the file in question has been modified.

If I understand your application correctly, you could also look into having a cron job delete files in that directory that are older than 30 minutes, and then rewriting on a file-nonexistence condition.

Comment: Yeap, obviously. But the Last-modified header does exist at that time, so I thought that perhaps there's something for that. I guess there isn't :-(

As for the cron, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 9):

No, that’s not possible. But you could use a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to get that information from a program with less overhead than PHP, maybe a shell script.

Here’s an example bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    max_age=${line%%:*}
    filename=${line#*:}
    if [[ -f $filename ]]; then
        lm=$(stat -f %m "$filename")
        if [[ $(date +%s)-$lm -le $max_age ]]; then
            echo yes
        else
            echo no
        fi
    else
        echo no
    fi
done
```

The declaration of the rewrite map needs to be placed in your server or virtual host configuraion file as the program is just started once and then waits for input:

```
RewriteMap last-modified-within prg:/absolute/file/system/path/to/last-modified-within.sh
```

And then you can use that rewrite map like this (.htaccess example):

```
RewriteCond %{last-modified-within:30:%{REQUEST_FILENAME}} =yes
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ script.php [L]
```

Comment: Since PHP is already loaded & running inside the Apache process, its not at all clear that spawning a new bash — one per request — will be faster. I'd guess it isn't.

Comment: Wow, that's smart! Thanks a lot for your time. However, what about derobert's objection above?

Comment: @derobert: Ah, sorry, forgot about that. The program is just started once and then waits for input on SDTIN.

Comment: I have to admit that it didn’t work for me. But that’s how it would be done.

Comment: Even if your bash script is staying running, you're still spawning at least a `stat` and a `date` for each request. BTW: Shouldn't that be `[ ... ]` not `[[ ... ]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using mod_proxy, mod_cache, and/or squid? It sounds like you're trying to roll your own caching...

Comment: Yeap, I'm trying to cache some php/gd generated images and recreate them every 30 minutes, if needed (=if someone actually requests them). You think mod_proxy, mod_cache or squid can help? I've never really looked into them to be frank. I always thought they are for more complicated things.

Comment: Yes, you're doing web caching, and that's exactly what those are intended for. Naturally, you should only bother with this optimization if it matters (e.g., you have the traffic volume to require it).